# TRANSPOSE function with condition of special date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have a perfectly working function:

TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(JOIN(" , , , , , ,";FILTER('REELsatış'!C2:C1500; 'REELsatış'!C2:C1500 <> "")));","))

It uses the data from the sheet REELsatış:

[image]

And gives me the following result on another sheet:

[image]

But it need it to use only the records of today. I mean that it shows 14.07.2021 today, and tomorrow it will show 15.07.2021. How can I put this condition in this complicated formula?

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" , , , , , ,"; 
 FILTER('REELsatış'!C2:C1500; DATEVALUE('REELsatış'!C2:C1500) = DATEVALUE(TODAY())))); ","))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer) Unfortunately, it can't filter the dates with the timestamps. Is it possible to make it see the date in the timestamps?

Comment: The timestamps are important, they are like the ID of the line.